# How to open .accdb file in Windows Phone 8.1 Application?

Tags: c#, database

I'm currently developing a Windows Phone Application and I want to work from a .accdb file. I already searched for this, but can't find a solution. Tried Linq to SQL, but this gives me an error:

`DataContext dc = new DataContext("Data Source=isostore:/test.accdb");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Microsoft Office Access isn't supported as database on the WP platform.

I would suggest to take a look at the article [Local database for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202860%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to see the viable options.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer.